# My form doesn't loop this correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to get this loop to work.

Once the submit button is clicked ten times it should revert to the main form; instead it's reverting as soon as the submit is clicked once.

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 mainMenu = new Form1();
    int repeat = 0;

    do
    {
        num1.Text = A1.firstRandomNumber().ToString();

        num2.Text = A1.secondRandomNumber().ToString();

        repeat++;

    } while (repeat <= 10);

    if (repeat == 11)
    {
        mainMenu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually after modifying it loops indefinitely...

Comment: You are loop ten summit button clicks you are looping ten time each time you click the button. You need to move the repeat variable out side the button click and add one each time you click the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything inside of `submit_Click` occurs for each click. That includes defining `repeat` anew, setting it to `0`, looping to increment it entirely to `11`, and swapping which form is visible.

If you want to count the number of clicks, you'll have to establish your counter outside of the handler so it can be incremented:

```
private int repeatSubmit = 0;

private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (repeatSubmit < 10)
    {
        num1.Text = A1.firstRandomNumber().ToString();
        num2.Text = A1.secondRandomNumber().ToString();
        repeatSubmit++;
    }
    else
    {
        mainMenu.Show();
        this.Hide();
        repeatSubmit = 0; // ready for the next time `this` form is shown
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need `if (repeat <= 10)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, you are waiting for the user to click the button 10 times? Or the loop is supposed to simulate 10 clicks?

This loop will enter (do) and set `num1` and `num2`, add one to repeat, and then do that 10 times until `repeat == 11`, and then it will display the main menu.

I think the code you make be looking for is as follows:

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    repeat ++;
    num1.Text = A1.firstRandomNumber().ToString();
    num2.Text = A2.secondRandomNumer().ToString();
    if(repeat >=10)
    {
        mainMenu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially I want the user to be able to click the submit button ten times then it'll revert to the main menu; right now it clicks once then reverts.

Comment: Okay, don't use a do while loop. Just increment a counter each button click, and once it hits ten, then show the main menu

Comment: You may or may not run into scope problems, depending on how the rest of your code is set up. You may need to either create a global variable for that counter or pass it by reference.

Answer (score 2):

As your code is, on 1 click you enter your loop where you proceed to increment the counter until it's equal to 11, then you exit your loop and show the main menu.  Basically you're not counting clicks.

What you want to do is store the counter somewhere, probably as a class variable.  Then every time you enter the click function you increment.  When the click function has been entered 10 times then you would go into your if statement.

```
private int clickCount = 0;

private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    clickCount++;
    // Other code that happens on a click

    if (clickCount == 10){  // 10th click show main menu
        // Code to show main menu
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to store it as a class variable. Having an example would be helpful to the OP too.

Comment: @JWLim The issue was edited - please remove the downvote if it was you, otherwise let me know what you still disagree with so it can be addressed.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. And I don't disagree with anything in it now.

Comment: @RayneBlackham Glad I could help - since you said both answers were useful you could make sure to upvote both.

Answer (score 0):

It runs through the loop on the first click of submit, if I understand what you are trying to achieve, you don't need a loop at all, just a counter for each time the button is pressed.